# rewrite plugin in smarty 3 syntax

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I need a rewrite in how the modifier 'truncate' is called, because it is causing an error.
**_getfilepath** does not exist in version 3

```
$this->_engine = new Smarty();
$this->_engine->template_dir = $config->paths->templates;
$this->_engine->compile_dir = sprintf('%s/tmp/templates_c',
                                      $config->paths->data);

 $this->_engine->plugins_dir = array($config->paths->base .
                           '/woonbel/include/Templater/plugins','plugins');



function smarty_function_breadcrumbs($params, $smarty)
{
    $defaultParams = array('trail'     => array(),
                           'separator' => ' &gt; ',
                           'truncate'  => 40);

    // initialize the parameters
    foreach ($defaultParams as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($params[$k]))
            $params[$k] = $v;
    }

    // load the truncate modifier
    if ($params['truncate'] > 0)
```

**require_once $smarty->getPluginsDir('modifier', 'truncate');**

```
 $links = array();
        $numSteps = count($params['trail']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numSteps; $i++) {
            $step = $params['trail'][$i];

            // truncate the title if required
            if ($params['truncate'] > 0)
                $step['title'] = smarty_modifier_truncate($step['title'],
                                                          $params['truncate']);

            // build the link if it's set and isn't the last step
            if (strlen($step['link']) > 0 && $i < $numSteps - 1) {
                $links[] = sprintf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>',
                                   htmlSpecialChars($step['link']),
                                   htmlSpecialChars($step['title']),
                                   htmlSpecialChars($step['title']));
            }
            else {
                // either the link isn't set, or it's the last step
                $links[] = htmlSpecialChars($step['title']);
            }
        }

        // join the links using the specified separator
        return join($params['separator'], $links);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for the (not publicly documented) loadPlugin() function:

```
$smarty->loadPlugin('smarty_modifier_truncate', true);
$string = smarty_modifier_truncate($string);
```

Update test case:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'path-to/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->loadPlugin('smarty_modifier_truncate', true);
$string = 'hello world I should be truncated to some smaller string';
$string = smarty_modifier_truncate($string, 10);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: I now get this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function smarty_modifier_truncate() in /home/woonbel/public_html/woonbel/include/Templater/plugins/function.breadcrumbs.php on line 28

Comment: I've supplied a test-case. check if that runs through

Comment: yes, that worked,must be something wrong with this then?$this->_engine->plugins_dir = array($config->paths->base .
                           '/woonbel/include/Templater/plugins','plugins');

Comment: I changed the path of the native plugins directory to an absolute one and that worked, but I would stil like to know why the relative diddn't work

Comment: I think because use_include_path was set to false